# Container image runs in Docker Swarm but not in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile

I have a Docker Swarm running a container with our custom code (.net core 3.1 on Linux) in with no issue. I have just setup a test 4 node Kubernetes cluster using Microk8s. When I load the image to Kubernetes, it appears to go through fine but the container starts and then stops immediately with error "Back-off restarting failed container". Looking at the error from the pod, I get "It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs. Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from: [https://aka.ms/dotnet-download"](https://aka.ms/dotnet-download%22).

The image is the same image running in the Swarm. My searches have led me to ENTRYPOINT potentially being the issue from the build dockerfile but I haven't had any luck with with changes to this. I have put my dockerfile below in case it is relevant to this problem.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# tzdata for timzone
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata

ARG REPO_TAG
ENV TZ UTC
ENV ApiVersion=$REPO_TAG

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj", "WebAPI/"]
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["Application/Application.csproj", "Application/"]
COPY ["Lib/*", "Lib/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPI.dll"]
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Output from kubectl describe pod:

```
Name:         v5api-945c4f96c-925dp
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         kube2/192.168.5.202
Start Time:   Wed, 29 Sep 2021 14:46:20 +0000
Labels:       app=v5api
              io.portainer.kubernetes.application.name=stepsv5api
              pod-template-hash=945c4f96c
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.1.2.82/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.1.2.82/32
Status:       Running
IP:           10.1.2.82
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.2.82
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/v5api-945c4f96c
Containers:
  v5api:
    Container ID:   containerd://5a8af38a90eb0e82c2760849d2d2be6418cd90581d7f4b4b97f01e91142ba019
    Image:          docker.io/privaterepo/v5api:latest
    Image ID:       docker.io/privaterepo/v5api@sha256:3d09dd399ea2a3252605cb32474d6d9f46a3b4f314f7e514597ed3421151ac20
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    145
      Started:      Wed, 29 Sep 2021 17:46:13 +0000
      Finished:     Wed, 29 Sep 2021 17:46:13 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  40
    Environment:
      TZ:                  Europe/London
    Mounts:
      /app from config-v5api-871dbe27-9933-416a-9830-ef1ec93a82e9 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-9sqch (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-v5api-871dbe27-9933-416a-9830-ef1ec93a82e9:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      appsettings-conf-v1
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-9sqch:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff  3m55s (x829 over 3h4m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Error from kubectl logs:

```
"It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work with kubernetes" , what is the status of your pod when this image is used, what is the `describe pod` output ? what is the output of `kubect logs` command?

Comment: @P.... I have added the output from the log and the describe pod to the original post. The status of the pod is that it is terminated because of the container error:  "It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs. Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from: https://aka.ms/dotnet-download".

Comment: try setting `dnsPolicy: Default` in your pod. error you shared says name resolution failed for `kube2` , which is apparently your node name.

Comment: Apologies, DNS wasn't configured, sorted that out now. I have updated the error for the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mounts:
  /app from config-v5api-871dbe27-9933-416a-9830-ef1ec93a82e9 (rw)
```

It appears you've replaced the entire `/app` directory that should contain your application with a volume mount to a ConfigMap. As a result, there's no application available inside the container to run.

Comment: Yeah, I just logged in to leave a comment saying I worked the problem out and you are indeed correct. I was treating the config map as if it would overwrite a single file rather than mount a new directory with the single file I am looking to overwrite. As I understand, if I use subpath, it will just overwrite the single file but changes to the configmap won’t feed through to the container automatically. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @dadinthemiddle glad that helped. Be sure to click the check next to the answer if it's resolved so it doesn't still show as open on the site.